# Detect WooCommerce order status changed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a simple WordPress plugin that adds some credits to a table when the admin marks a order as "completed".
 My plugin.php looks like this:

```
<?php 
   function add_credits($order_status, $order_id) {
        global $wpdb, $woocommerce, $current_user;
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        $items = $order->get_items();

         //DO SOME STUFF HERE with items and order
   }//function

   add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed',   'add_credits');
```

But, when I change the order to "COMPLETE", this plugin does not make nothing. I can even write an echo or a simple instruction at the first line of the function, and doesn't run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `add_credits` should take only one parameter:

`function add_credits($order_id) {`

Also make sure your plugin is activated in WordPress.

You can check the sourcecode containing the specific `do_action` call here:
http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#_update_status